# Is there a way to merge struct types / extend a struct in Zig?

Tags: inheritance, struct, zig

I have two struct types:

```
const BaseStruct = struct {
    foo: f64,
    bar: f64
};

const AdditionalFields = struct {
    baz: u64,
};
```

Is there a – preferably simple – way to create (at comptime) a third struct type from the former two which is equivalent to

```
const ExtendedStruct = struct {
    foo: f64,
    bar: f64,
    baz: u64,
};
```

? (How about if I want all three struct types to be `packed`?)

Basically, I want to "extend" `BaseStruct`, i.e. create a "subtype" of `BaseStruct` that comes with additional fields.

I'm imagining something like:

```
const ExtendedStruct = @mergeStruct(BaseStruct, AdditionalFields);
```

or

```
const ExtendedStruct = struct {
    ...BaseStruct, // unpacks (destructures) BaseStruct
    ...AdditionalFields, // Alternatively, write `baz: u64` directly
});
```

Comment: you have to use `@Type(.{ .Struct = .{ ... } })`

Comment: Thanks, @AliChraghi! I was afraid that it was a bit more involved.